# Is there any way to pause a HTTP request using chrome.webRequest without locking the entire browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to display headers intercepted with chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders to the user for editing, preferably using chrome.tabs.executeScript. However, chrome.tabs.executeScript is asynchronous and I can't find a way to wait for it to return without freezing the entire browser.

In other words, I'm aiming for what the code below gives, except with a HTML UI and without freezing any unrelated tabs.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {
    for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
      if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
          var foo = prompt('User-Agent', details.requestHeaders[i].value);
          // chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId,{code:""});
          //^create a nice HTML overlay & pass the user input back
          details.requestHeaders[i].value = foo;
         break;
      }
    }
    return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
  },
  {urls: ["http://*/*"], types: ["main_frame"]},
  ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

If it's impossible that'd be nice to know too, since I could file a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Promises are only supported by Firefox's webRequest API.

You should use promises, you can (for example) create a sleep command that holds up the current thread until a promise value is returned after X seconds (or when you are done editing the headers):

```
const sleep = async seconds => {
    return new Promise(async(resolve)=>{
        setTimeout(resolve, seconds * 1000);
    });
}
```

Please note that asynchronous functions must be called on an asynchronous thread, so you should initiate your app (or just your listener function) inside an asynchronous function. This can be an anonymous function if you like (a function with no name):

```
(async()=>{
    await sleep(2);
    // do something after waiting 2 seconds.
})();
```

A working example in your case would be to declare your blocking listener function as asynchronous, like so:

```
const promptUserToEditHeaders = async details => {
    return new Promise(async(resolve)=>{
        // prompt the user to edit the request headers
        // then call resolve() when you are done editing headers
    });
}

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    async details => {
        await promptUserToEditHeaders(details);
    },
    {urls: ["http://*/*"], types: ["main_frame"]},
    ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]
);
```

Read more about JavaScript promises: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Read more about async and await: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: This answer is completely wrong because it's for Firefox WebExtensions, not for Chrome extensions where webRequest API doesn't support delayed responses or Promise regardless of using polyfills.

Comment: @wOxxOm OP is asking for a way to edit request headers without freezing/halting the page load, not response headers. My answer also clearly shows `chrome` instead of `browser`, which would be the case for Firefox.

Comment: No, you're missing the point: "delayed response" means a callback that returns asynchronously. The webRequest API in Chrome extensions doesn't support it, and it doesn't matter if you use `chrome`. You're looking in the wrong documentation.

Comment: @wOxxOm you also say a "delayed response" involves an asynchronous callback. This is false. Synchronous execution must complete before the next function is called. If it does not block/delay the execution, then it's called asynchronous.

Comment: Yet again you've missed the point. Your code adds an `async` function as a listener which means that it returns a Promise, which won't be resolved by webRequest API because it doesn't support promises. It means that your onBeforeSendHeaders is useless. To make it work you need to return an object from the listener directly as shown in the documentation. Nothing in your answer will help solve the problem.

Comment: @wOxxOm my apologies, it seems this functionality is only supported in Firefox, like you stated. My example solves the problem (only in Firefox), provided that OP creates a Promise that opens a UI, and resolves when the user has replied to a runtime message containing the request data. It amazes me that such basic functionality has not been implemented in Chrome ‍♂

Comment: I guess the only workaround is to bypass the blocking entirely, and set predefined conditions that will alter the request data synchronously.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if this will work, but worth a shot.

You could set up a while loop that holds the return until your executed scripts returns a message via [Message Passing](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/messaging.html). Also, you will need to use the `webRequestBlocking` permission in your manifest (which you probably already have).

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
    function(details) {
        var holdReturn = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
            if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'User-Agent') {
                holdReturn = true;
                chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(
                    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
                        if (request.userAgentOverride) {
                            details.requestHeaders[i].value = request.userAgentOverride;
                            holdReturn = false;
                        }
                    });

                chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId,{file: "user-agent-dialog.js"});
                break;
            }
        }

        while (holdReturn) {
            // waiting...
        }

        return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
     },
  {urls: ["http://*/*"], types: ["main_frame"]},
  ["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

The `user-agent-dialog.js` file would then have:

```
function onFormSubmit() {
    chrome.extension.sendRequest(null, {
        userAgentOverride: userAgentValueFromInput
    });
}

// code to create the dialog and form, this will call
// onFormSubmit() when the form is submitted to send a 
// message back to the background page.
```

Comment: It appears that the busy wait loop prevents the user-agent-dialog.js from executing indefinitely, unless it is executed on a different tab from the originating one. So chrome.tabs.executeScript(details.tabId never executes but chrome.tabs.executeScript(<randomtabId) does.
Unfortunately regardless of which tab it originates from chrome.extension.sendRequest just hangs. Probably thanks to the busy wait, again.

Comment: That while wait loop will overwhelm the CPU and kill your browser!