# Hold HTTP request with chrome.webRequest until some async function is resolved

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, async-await

Basically I need to stop an HTTP request, send it to an app to determine weather or not it should be blocked and then take the appropriate action. A simplified version of the code would look something like:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener( async details => {
        let policy = await getPolicy(details); 
        return {cancel: result}
    },
    {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
    ["requestHeaders", "blocking"]
);
```

with the getPolicy function sending the info to a policy server to determine weather or not to block the request and then return a boolean result. The problem boils down to while I am waiting for a policy result the listener doesn't continue to hold the request but just allows all request through before a result is returned. I based this current code off of the similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57301607/16531716
That answer however doesn't seem to actually work.
(I am using Manifest V2 because that is the only way I can use the blocking permission. MV2 doesn't normally support async operations but I'm also using the Mozilla polyfill module to add them so that isn't the issue)

Comment: In Chrome you can't delay webRequest's response. It must be synchronous, no async/await.

Comment: Note that your using a polyfill doesn't change the underlying *architectural* restrictions.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. Do you know any other way I could achieve something similar in a synchronously?

Comment: You'll have to make the request synchronously.

Comment: I can't have the policies preset as rules on the extension otherwise I would just use MV3 and the declarativeNetRequest system

Comment: Use XMLHttpRequest to send the request *synchronously*.